# How many languages can be used in the JSP

Tags: java, jsp

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with JSP front-end languages, I already read some books of JSP. I knew I can write script of `Java` in JSP with <%...%>. and also `EL`, `JSTL`, `Custom Tag`(Anything else ? Please correct me if there is wrong.) . And As a web page of HTML, We can always use `Javascript` or java script library like `Jquery` etc to access DOM or access back end with `AJAX`.

But there always exist a question bother me. How many languages can be used in the JSP? I don't know if there are any more except the ones I mentioned above.

I hope someone can help me figure out it. Thanks.

**Updated**

Thanks Stephen's kindly and valuable help to me, No matter what kinds of expressions or tag are used in `JSP`, They are different from the script that web browser directly can understand. They are understood by `JAVA` of the back-end web server like `tomcat` ,`jboss` etc. and will be compiled into a `Servlet` class before they are ready to work. And like any other web page like `ASP`,`PHP`etc. The class will generate html response to the web client request. :)  If I didn't misunderstand your meaning . If possible , Anyone can build his owner language engine which host in the web server.

So like what you said `It is not possible to enumerate the languages that could be "used" in a JSP.` . Right ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to enumerate the languages that could be "used" in a JSP.

> And As a web page of HTML, We can always use Javascript or java script library like Jquery etc to access DOM or access back end with AJAX.

Those are not languages that JSP understands.  Rather they are (as far as JSP is concerned) just content that goes into the document generated by the JSP.

As a corollary, you could embed **any language you wanted** to the JSP ... provided that the "client" that gets the resulting document knows how to deal with it.

---

Even the (alternative) question - *"what languages that a web browser will understand can I use in a JSP"* - doesn't have a simple answer.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I should say How many scripts or expressions can be used in JSP ?

Comment: @Joe.wang - Same answer.  You need to understand what I wrote if you are going to refine your question into something that has a concrete answer.

Comment: Correct.  That is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure your server and what browsers you are targeting.

The Java codes and JSP tags (EL, JSTL, Custom Tag, etc.) are processed on the server side. But with some configuration, you can even put PHP code in the JSP page.

Modern browsers supports JavaScript, and jQuery etc. are just frameworks not languages built on JavaScript.

Browsers under Windows would support VBScript. There are JavaApplets or Flash which can help you make some more powerful web applications.